# Converting Oracle SQL query with left outer join to Linq

Tags: linq

I'm trying to convert the Oracle Sql query below to linq, without much success. I'm not sure how to handle the line `AND ShipSeq = i.ShipSeq(+)`, which I've learned is a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in Oracle. I'm testing the Linq query below in LinqPad, where I don't get any syntax errors but it errors on executing the query. Any ideas?

**Oracle Sql Query**

```
SELECT *
FROM   CustomerShip,
    (SELECT DISTINCT b.ShipSeq AS shipSeq
     FROM   Orders a,
            CustomerShip b
     WHERE  a.OrderId IN (SELECT OrderId
                          FROM   Orders
                          WHERE  CustomerId = @CustomerId
                          AND    OrderType <> 'A')
     AND    b.CustomerId = @CustomerId
     AND    b.ShipSeq = a.CustShip
     AND    OrderStatus <> 'C'
     GROUP BY b.ShipSeq) i
WHERE  CustomerId = @CustomerId
AND    (Address NOT LIKE '%RETAIL%STORE%')
AND    ShipSeq = i.ShipSeq(+)
ORDER BY ShipTo DESC, OrderDate DESC;
```

**Linq Query**

```
var query = from s in CustomerShip
            join m in Orders on s.ShipTo equals m.ShipTo into temp
            from x in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where (from o in Orders
                   from c in CustomerShip
                   where (from x in CustomerOrders
                          where x.CustomerId == customerId
                          && !x.OrderType.Equals("A")
                          select x.OrderId).Contains(o.OrderId)
                     && c.CustomerId == customerId
                     && c.ShipTo == o.ShipTo
                     && !o.OrderStatus.Equals("C")
                     select c.ShipTo).Distinct().Contains(s.ShipTo)
            && s.CustomerId == customerId
            && !s.Address.Contains("RETAIL")
            && !s.Address.Contains("STORE")
            orderby s.ShipTo descending, s.OrderDate descending
            select s;
```

Comment: This might help (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) There's a section on joins

Answer (score 0):

I think a literal translation looks like this:

```
var iQuerySub = from o in Orders where o.CustomerId == pCustomerId && o.OrderType != "A" select o.OrderId;

var iQuery = (from a in Orders
              from b in CustomerShip
              where iQuerySub.Contains(a.OrderId) &&
              b.CustomerId == pCustomerId &&
              b.ShipSeq == a.CustShip &&
              a.OrderStatus != "C"
              group b by b.ShipSeq into bg
              select new { shipSeq = bg.Key }).Distinct();

var ans = from s in CustomerShip
          where s.CustomerId == pCustomerId &&
          (!s.Address.Contains("RETAIL") || !s.Address.Contains("STORE") || s.Address.IndexOf("RETAIL") > s.Address.IndexOf("STORE"))
          join i in iQuery on s.ShipSeq equals i.shipSeq into ij
          from i in ij.DefaultIfEmpty()
          orderby s.ShipTo, s.OrderDate descending
          select new { s, shipSeq = (i != null ? i.shipSeq : (int?)null) };
```

But both the SQL and LINQ seem inefficient to me, but without domain knowledge this is all I could optimize:

```
var iQuery2 = (from b in CustomerShip
               where b.CustomerId == pCustomerId &&
               Orders.Any(a => a.CustomerId == pCustomerId && a.OrderType != "A" && a.OrderStatus != "C" && b.ShipSeq == a.CustShip)
               select new { shipSeq = b.ShipSeq }).Distinct();

var ans2 = from s in CustomerShip
           where s.CustomerId == pCustomerId &&
           (!s.Address.Contains("RETAIL") || !s.Address.Contains("STORE") || s.Address.IndexOf("RETAIL") > s.Address.IndexOf("STORE"))
           join i in iQuery2 on s.ShipSeq equals i.shipSeq into ij
           from i in ij.DefaultIfEmpty()
           orderby s.ShipTo, s.OrderDate descending
           select new { s, shipSeq = (i != null ? i.shipSeq : (int?)null) };
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. Your answer is almost working for me, but on the `iQuery` query I get an error when testing in LinqPad: `not a GROUP BY expression`

Comment: I think I have identified the issue, but not sure how to correct. When I view the generated SQL, it has a `GROUP BY b.ShipSeq`, but the first line in the query is `SELECT b.ShipSeq, c.OrderId`. Not sure why the `c.OrderId` is in the select statement?

Comment: That would probably be how the `iQuerySub` is being implemented by LINQ in order to process the `where iQuerySub.Contains` it needs the `OrderId`. I ran this in LINQPad on a anonymous object model, but obviously I don't have your real database or even the schema, so I am not sure if my model is correct - in the translation I had to guess as to what table some columns belong to without the scheme or a clear alias expression.